# Using 2 different airlines for outbound & return flight to U.S?

Tags: air-travel, lhr, jfk, lax

I'm travelling to the U.S, am i allowed to go with 2 diffent airlines? For example fly out wit BA & come back with Virgin Atlanctic? or do i have to come back with the same company?

I will be flying from Heathrow to JFK but returning from LAX to Heathrow ..

Comment: Why do you think this should be a problem?

Comment: The simplest way to use 2 different airlines is to buy 2 different tickets.

Answer (score 1):

The only potential problem is that you may be asked to show a return ticket (or evidence of an e-ticket, I suppose) in order to enter the US, as evidence of your intention to leave.  In practice, I have never seen or heard of anyone being required to show that.

If it should happen to you, the border guard would not care whether the return ticket is a one-way ticket on a different airline or half of a return ticket.  To be safe, therefore, it would be a good idea to buy the ticket for your return journey before you leave home.